# How to create a conditional multipage report in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2016

I am creating an SSRS report (on SQL Server 2016) which will generate letters to a set of names in our database.  If the recipient of this letter is married (if Spouse in the dataset is not blank), then we need to create an exact copy of the same letter on the following page but using the Spouse's name as the recipient instead.

I used a List control and populated it with the text and the merge fields and it all works great, but now I need to account for spouses.

It seems to me that I would need to use a conditional page break on the List control, which seems straightforward enough, but I am clueless as to how to approach the data fields.  In the "Name" area of the letter, I would need the field to pull Recipient on the first page and Spouse on the second IF Recipient is married.  Otherwise I need it to pull Recipient only and then move on to the next record without breaking the page.

Any input on how to accomplish this would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you union the spouse data and the primary recipient data into a single dataset and then just process that. This would mean no changes to the report design.

Without seeing your dataset of the dataset query this is a guess but something along the lines of

```
SELECT PersonID, FirstName, LastName
    FROM myTable
UNION
SELECT PersonID, SpouseFisrtName, SpouseLastName
    FROM myTable
ORDER BY PersonID
```

Comment: Brilliant solution!  I'm much more experienced with Crystal Reports, so it's a challenge to figure out how to do the same things in SSRS... and I often forget that SSRS has more power and flexibility with the data set.  Thanks so much Alan!

Comment: You're welcome. SSRS has its advantages but sometimes lacks things that are simple in CR